# How can I use the spare capacity in a std::vector?

Tags: c++, stdvector

What is the safe, portable, idiomatic way to use the spare capacity in a `std::vector`?

```
std::vector<Foo> foos;
foos.emplace_back(1);
foos.emplace_back(2);
foos.reserve(10);
```

At this point, `foos` owns at least `8 * sizeof(Foo)` uninitialized spare memory starting at `foos.data() + foos.size()`. It seems terribly inefficient to let that memory go to waste. How can I use this spare capacity as scratch space or for other purposes before I fill it with `Foo` objects by appending to `foos`? What is the right way to do this without invoking any undefined behavior?

Comment: why would you want to?  If you need scratch space, allocate it for itself.  If you don't need the extra capacity in the vector yet, don't reserve it yet.

Comment: First, there should be a reason for explicit pre-allocation of memory, which means that if we command a vector to `reserve` some memory, this vector will probably need it on its own soon.

Comment: You don't own the memory, and there is no legal defined use of it, so ANYTHING you do with it (other than letting the vector fill it with objects) will be undefined behavior.

Comment: I know that my vector will have up to 10 `Foo`s total. I'd like to be able to use the spare capacity for calculations needed to generate those `Foo`s. The 10 is a runtime number, so using an array on the stack is not possible. Using a separate allocation requires, well, a separate new/delete or malloc/free.

Comment: I don't believe you can. A vector is a generic class in the standard library. When you reserve, you are allocating memory. The owner of the memory is the vector class instance. Nothing else can touch it.

Comment: You're [in X-Y space](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. If you explain what problem you need this potential solution for, odds are good that someone here can offer a better-suited solution.

Comment: There's not.  If you use the additional reserved memory for something else, you cause any operations that resize the vector (set its reported size, as distinct from its reported capacity) to have undefined behaviour - since all operations that change the size of a vector ASSUME they have exclusive access to that reserved memory unless they explicitly release it.     Also, look up "premature optimization" if you want a discussion of the pitfalls of doing micro-optimisation of code - which is what you are trying to do.,

Comment: The entire implementation of `std::vector` is opaque and not specified.  Even if you find some magic way to use the allocated space, there's a chance that the next version of the compiler will break it.  Don't go there.

Comment: So much written about why I shouldn't, so little about how I could.

Comment: "So much written about why I shouldn't, so little about how I could." Perhaps there's a good reason for that. Simply put, you cannot "without invoking any undefined behavior" as you asked.

Comment: The fact you can't use that space in any meaningful way is because this is already solving a trade off of space vs performance (# allocations + internal moves ). You cannot have your cake and eat it too. If you want to use the "two ends" of a single memory allocation you can code your own data structure. This is not part of the standard, I think Knuth describes it in his book(s). It is an interesting data structure.

Comment: What's wrong with using the 8 MiB of stack space you have? There is always going to be some wasted space in programs. Be it from the page alignment requirements for executable vs r/w memory, to preallocation of memory for malloc, to the little bits of space in each allocation that weren't used because malloc is most likely a slab allocator.

Comment: "What's wrong with using the 8 MiB of stack space you have?" It is not big enough to hold the 4-16 GiB of data I know my vector will contain. Allocating a second 4-16 GiB temporary buffer for scratch calculations really is too big an ask. Yes, it must be contiguous. No, the intermediate values aren't `Foo`s. Yes, I could do this all manually or by making non-portable assumptions. But I like leading a horse to water and feeding it the whole cake.

Answer (score 9):

> How can I use the spare capacity in a std::vector?

By inserting more elements.

---

More convoluted answer which may be what you're looking for, but probably more complex than it's worth:

You can allocate memory yourself (`std::allocator` or whatever; don't forget `std::unique_ptr`), and implement a custom allocator that uses that piece of memory. You can then use that memory for whatever and later create a vector using the custom allocator. Note that this doesn't let you use the memory that has already been reserved for the vecor; you can only use the memory before it has been acquired by the vector.

Comment: I agree with your point, but the question was about how to use the reserved capacity BEFORE inserting elements.

Comment: @Peter, this answer is very telling. The only way to use the reserved space of a vector is to insert more elements (but less than the capacity), One could have an additional iterator to mark the conceptual "end" of the vector and the start of the "extra" elements and basically invent a data structure. Very limited, yes, but still.

Comment: @Peter I expanded the answer with something that may be useful to someone.

Comment: Is there a way to allocate a `10 * sizeof(Foo)` buffer, construct 5 `Foo`s in it, then give ownership of this buffer to a `vector`?

Comment: @Filipp As I described, you could reuse the memory of that buffer for the custom allocator.

Comment: But how can I tell the `std::vector` "This buffer already has N `Foo`s in it?"

Comment: @Filipp The vector just overwrites the memory. It doesn't need to know what was there before.

Comment: @eerorika The goal of my question is to have a single buffer that is partially occupied by `Foo`s and partially not, then end up with a `vector` that owns those `Foo`s.

Comment: @Filipp If you want vector to own the Foos, then you must initially create them inside the vector. You won't be able to safely use the rest of the memory in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, memory for unused elements is wasted, but it is unavoidable. It's by [design](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

> The storage of the vector is handled automatically, being expanded and
> contracted as needed. Vectors usually occupy more space than static
> arrays, because more memory is allocated to handle future growth. This
> way a vector does not need to reallocate each time an element is
> inserted, but only when the additional memory is exhausted.

---

It's also good to know some non-standard vector's variants and may use them as replacement for `std::vector`, they
have specific application scenarios.

If you need a dynamic array and the maximum capacity is know at compile time，then [boost::static_vector](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.small_vector) would be a choice(Use it may avoid the unnecessary memory waste of std::vector since most of std::vector's implementation always reserve capacity with a pow of 2, so if your desired capacity is 10, then 6 elements is likely to
be waste):

> static_vector is an hybrid between vector and array: like vector, it's
> a sequence container with contiguous storage that can change in size,
> along with the static allocation, low overhead, and fixed capacity of
> array. static_vector is based on Adam Wulkiewicz and Andrew Hundt's
> high-performance varray class.
>
> The number of elements in a static_vector may vary dynamically up to a
> fixed capacity because elements are stored within the object itself
> similarly to an array. However, objects are initialized as they are
> inserted into static_vector unlike C arrays or std::array which must
> construct all elements on instantiation. The behavior of static_vector
> enables the use of statically allocated elements in cases with complex
> object lifetime requirements that would otherwise not be trivially
> possible. Some other properties:
>
> Random access to elements Constant time insertion and removal of
> elements at the end Linear time insertion and removal of elements at
> the beginning or in the middle. static_vector is well suited for use
> in a buffer, the internal implementation of other classes, or use
> cases where there is a fixed limit to the number of elements that must
> be stored. Embedded and realtime applications where allocation either
> may not be available or acceptable are a particular case where
> static_vector can be beneficial.

And if the dynamic array mostly has a very small size(only some of them would be large but with a small probability), then we may consider using [small_vector](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.small_vector), a small vector will improve the performance for such a scenario and such container is widely used in large projects.

> small_vector is a vector-like container optimized for the case when it
> contains few elements. It contains some preallocated elements
> in-place, which allows it to avoid the use of dynamic storage
> allocation when the actual number of elements is below that
> preallocated threshold. small_vector is inspired by LLVM's SmallVector
> container. Unlike static_vector, small_vector's capacity can grow
> beyond the initial preallocated capacity.